# Aapplication using Outlook failing to send emails - when started from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, outlook

I have built a small application which periodically sends emails to different recipients.

Code is pretty simple using C#:

```
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
...
OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.To = "bla@bla.bla";
mailItem.Subject = "Random subject";
mailItem.Body = "Random body";
mailItem.Send();
```

When I run .exe located on my machine it successfully sends an email, but when it's being run from task scheduler it hits some errors.

This is a result of task scheduler running this exe
[image]

Also, it's not hitting some exceptions from the task scheduler, it seems just to be timing out, I guess waiting for Outlook for some permissions.

Also Outlook programmatic access is set to:

[image]

====================================

Edit1: Program is timing out @ OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();

Comment: Why use Outlook interop?

Comment: @CaiusJard, To be honest, I was googling around to find the fastest code snippet which would use my machine's Outlook from C# app to send emails. I could use any (other) class/lib.

Comment: Unless you have no access to an smtp server (exchange only?) I'd consider using system.net.mail... I suspect the root cause of the current problem is a permissions issue though

Comment: (Permissions issue caused by the user that the task scheduler is impersonating to launch the task having fewer permissions than you who runs the task nonscheduled)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the task scheduler task is configured to run using the proper computer/network/domain account (e.g. the credentials you typed in when you ran the app on your machine). The local system account (windows default) falls outside this category.

Comment: I have set same local user which I use to log onto PC, to run the task. I run my .exe double clicked on a desktop so I guess it's being run from the local user?

Comment: I started printf debugging and program is timing out at line: OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();